How to create an Hour, Minute, Second countdown timer in WinForms using C#?
I am new to coding and currently working on a project in WinForms using C#. I want to create a countdown timer that displays hours, minutes, and seconds. However, I’m unsure how to implement this feature.
I’ve tried searching online and found several examples, but most of them either:
1 Count upwards instead of downwards, or
2 Only handle countdowns in seconds, without formatting them into hours, minutes, and seconds.
So far, I have not been able to piece together a working solution for this requirement.
Could someone guide me through the process of creating an Hour, Minute, Second countdown timer in WinForms?

Which part exactly is stopping you? Can you try and start with any version of countdown and then expand to the exact formatting desired? That would give us some code to work with.

Stack Overflow isn't meant to provide guides or tutorials.  Questions should be narrowly focused on a specific programming problem / error, and should provide enough context (such as debugging details, a minimal reproduceable code example, research information and explanations about what was tried and details about how the attempt didn't work, etc) for answers to be objectively judged as right or wrong.

Sure, many of us could. However, that's not the purpose of this site. Try it yourself and come back with a specific question if you get stuck.


Get input from the user for how much time they want to set the timer for. A common format is "hh:mm:ss" (two digit hours, minutes, and seconds, separated by colons). Convert this to a TimeSpan var userSetTime = TimeSpan.Parse(userInput). 2. Determine the end time: var endTime = DateTime.Now.Add(userSetTime). 3. while(endTime > DateTime.Now), print the remaining time, which is (endTime - DateTime.Now).ToString("c"). 4. At the end of the loop, the time is up. Sound an alarm.


Note, what I wrote is not the best way to do it, it's just a simple way to start thinking about the problem. Give it a shot and come back if you get stuck!
